# Xamarin.Forms.Maps vs Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I'm learning Xamarin and I noticed there are two ways of implementing maps, both have official documentation on MS docs pages.

- [Xamarin.Forms.Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/)
- [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api)

I couldn't find any information on what is the difference between both approaches. Which one should I use?

Comment: forms is the crossplatform version which internally uses {Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps on android platform](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/f1005105a668f49c2e97b4fbe45a022d8519c44e/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.csproj#L26)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps` is how you would add maps to a Xamarin.Android App, when *not* using Xamarin.Forms.

If you look at the [Xamarin.Forms.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/5.0.0.1558-pre3) the list of dependencies for Xamarin.Android contains `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps`.

What `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` does is to abstract Google Maps to be used from a Xamarin.Forms App.